# How to Change Static and Dynamic parameters Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am working with `Oracle 19c` in `Centos 7.` After the installation, I want to Change **Static** and **dynamic** parameters of the newly created database.

After that, I need to read the **alert log** to witness the Changes.

Already I registered **Pluggable Database(PDB)** with a new Created Listener.

How can I change these parameters??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to use v$parameter and v$spparameter views:

```sql
select * from v$parameter;
select * from v$spparameter;
```

Description:

[v$parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-PARAMETER.html#GUID-C86F3AB0-1191-447F-8EDF-4727D8693754)

[v$spparameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SPPARAMETER.html)

```
Describing VIEW  SYS.V_$PARAMETER...
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NUM                                                NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(80)
 TYPE                                               NUMBER
 VALUE                                              VARCHAR2(4000)
 DISPLAY_VALUE                                      VARCHAR2(4000)
 DEFAULT_VALUE                                      VARCHAR2(255)
 ISDEFAULT                                          VARCHAR2(9)
 ISSES_MODIFIABLE                                   VARCHAR2(5)
 ISSYS_MODIFIABLE                                   VARCHAR2(9)
 ISPDB_MODIFIABLE                                   VARCHAR2(5)
 ISINSTANCE_MODIFIABLE                              VARCHAR2(5)
 ISMODIFIED                                         VARCHAR2(10)
 ISADJUSTED                                         VARCHAR2(5)
 ISDEPRECATED                                       VARCHAR2(5)
 ISBASIC                                            VARCHAR2(5)
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(255)
 UPDATE_COMMENT                                     VARCHAR2(255)
 HASH                                               NUMBER
 CON_ID                                             NUMBER
```